# How to define REST url's for child objects

Tags: rest

A customer can have multiple addresses, I am doubtful of naming REST url's for address. CustomerAddresses is a standalone table with foreign key reference to Customer table.

Gets all addresses of customers (HttpGet)

```
/customers/{customerId}/addresses
```

Add new customer address (HttpPost)

```
/customers/{customerId}/addresses
```

Delete customer address (HttpDelete)

```
/customers/{customerId}/addresses/{addressId}
```

(OR)

Gets all addresses of customers (it is same as above)

```
/customers/{customerId}/addresses
```

Add new customer address (HttpPost) and body includes customerId.

```
/customeraddresses
```

Delete customer address (HttpDelete)

```
/customeraddresses/{addressId}
```

Comment: From a technological standpoint the second solution is totally fine, from a data-modeling point of view I'd use the first one as "normally" you would define the ID of a customer address as a composite key referring to the primary key of a customer so that an address wouldn't have a unique ID on its own

Comment: What happens if you have other things (except customers) that have addresses? What happens if two customers live on the same address? One idea could be to have addresses at `/adress/{addressId}` and have `/customers/{customerId}/addresses` return a bunch of IDs which then requires looking them up (or just include those address-IDs in the response from `/customers/{customerId}`. Otherwise I think your first example looks OK.

Comment: Thank you both, right now they are not stand alone addresses and IS dependent on the customer. I am going with option 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your examples are *fine*.  General purpose components don't care whether or not your resource identifiers use spellings that match the names you use in your private internal storage.

So you can use whatever spellings are convenient for your human beings.

This might mean preferring

- spellings that are easy to document for consumers
- spellings that are easy to route, internally
- spellings that are easy to recognize, when you are reading an access log
- none of the above.

The path part of a URI is fundamentally hierarchical - it may be convenient to choose spellings that allow you to use dot segments to reference other resources.

---

Keep in mind that you data model and your resource model are *different* things, and should be allowed to change independently.  If changes to your table names also force changes to your resource identifier spellings, someone, somewhere, is probably going to have a bad time.